# Contradiction in filling sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> Retrofitted with stabilizing devices, some of which _____its  aesthetics,
>   the bridge has been reopened, no longer prone to excessive swaying but
>   not quite the breathtaking structure it originally was.

For the above blacks we have three choices and have to pick two of them.

1. impair
2. resist
3. compromise

It seems to me that, impair and resit completely suit  with the blank but ans is given impair and comprmise.

**Their explanation:**

> Though “resist” makes some sense when inserted into the blank, it does
>   not produce a sentence with the same meaning as either of these

Can you explain how they are right?

Comment: Didn't you want the blank before "its"?

Comment: right you are. sorry .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Resist" means to fight against something or try to stop something ([Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resist)). In this case, you cannot write "Retrofitted with stabilizing devices, some of which **resist** aesthetics, the bridge has been reopened, no longer prone to excessive swaying but not quite the breathtaking structure it originally was," because there is no struggle between two things. The aesthetics are not fighting back against the new stabilizers. On the other hand, "impair" and "compromise" can both have the sense of "make a bit worse," so it makes sense to say that the new stabilizers make the aesthetics a bit worse.